# NodeJS SSL Error

Tags: node.js, express

I can't seem to get SSL working for a V0.10.3 NodeJS app that uses Express 3 under Ubuntu 12.04. I'm getting the following error in Chrome:

```
Error 107 (net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR): SSL protocol error
```

I have the following in my app.js file:

```
var privateKey = fs.readFileSync('./ssl/private.key');
var certificate = fs.readFileSync('./ssl/cert.crt');
var godaddy = fs.readFileSync('./ssl/gd_bundle.crt');

var options = {
        key: privateKey,
        cert: certificate,
        ca: godaddy
};
https.createServer(options, app).listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("Express https server listening on port 3000");
});
```

A similar setup using a self-signed cert works just fine on my development box. Any idea where I'm going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

If it is working on Firefox but not on Chrome then check the settings in Chrome.

1. Go to Settings > Advanced Settings > Network > Change Proxy Settings.
2. It will open IE settings panel
3. Go to Advanced Tab > Security Options group at bottom
4. Try checking SSL 2.0 (or different SSL/TLS versions)

Comment: Firefox  doesn't work either. It says: The connection was interrupted while the page was loading. Manually with curl -kv gives:

* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* Unknown SSL protocol error in connection
* Closing connection #0

Comment: Keys maybe causing this. http://blog.techstacks.com/2010/03/3-common-causes-of-unknown-ssl-protocol-errors-with-curl.html. Can you verify the key/cert files. See http://www.madboa.com/geek/openssl/#verify-standard

Answer (score 0):

I got it working...thanks for your help though. I must have had some sort of file level issue because when I restored the ssl files from backup it worked.

Comment: what was the problem? I have the same issue with Network Solutions certificate.

Comment: Sorry Guy...I'm not sure. I restored from backup and it started working so I suspect a file level issue of some sort. I didn't investigate further.